# How do I ensure that my datetime period overlaps an existing period?

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have this

```
Dictionary<(DateTime from, DateTime to), HashSet<string>> uniquelyChangedPeriods = new();
```

in which I store unique string from a given time period

so ex.

between (from: 2020-01-01T00:00:00Z, to:2022-01-01T00:00:00Z) I could store string such as {"Hi","Adress", "Something"}
Lets say I then want to add a change registered in (2020-01-01T00:00:00Z, 2021-01-01T00:00:00Z) {"Hi","Adress", "Something2"}

but since (2020-01-01T00:00:00Z,2021-01-01T00:00:00Z) is included in (from: 2020-01-01T00:00:00Z , to:2022-01-01T00:00:00Z), I want to include the "Something2" in the entry (from: 2020-01-01T00:00:00Z , to:2022-01-01T00:00:00Z) and not create a seperate entry in the dictionary for this... how do easily do this overlap checking, and ensure it is included in the overlapping timeframe?

Comment: You want (2020, 2021) to overwrite (2020,2022)?

Comment: @LukaSamkharadze I want to be able to select the key, which is overlapping with given change period.

Comment: Why you use a dictionary instead an IEnumerable

Comment: Or why you use DateTime if you use them as int?

Comment: As I only wants unique change periods and the largest possible..

Comment: Changed to datetime @LeandroBardelli

Comment: Datetime doesn't check if periods are the same, you can repeat datetimes. Is very common that two events ocurrs in the same millisecond.

Comment: @LeandroBardelli no but inserting into a dictionary will instantly tell me, whether I am using an already known key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way you could go about this:

```
Dictionary<(DateTime from, DateTime to), HashSet<string>> uniquelyChangedPeriods = new();

var ((from, to), addData) = ((new DateTime(2020, 1, 1), new DateTime(2021, 1, 1)), new[]{ "test" });

var existing = uniquelyChangedPeriods.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key.from <= from && x.Key.to >= to);
if (existing.Value != null)
{
    foreach (var a in addData) existing.Value.Add(a);
}
else
{
    var set = new HashSet<string>();
    foreach (var a in addData) set.Add(a);
    uniquelyChangedPeriods.Add((from, to), set);
}
```

However, you might want to reconsider your design and approach here. Using a dictionary in this way will work, but may prove difficult to maintain down the line.

*Edit:*

For example, the current approach does not account for a potential case where the new period completely or partially overlaps the existing one and spans beyond the boundaries of that existing one. To better deal with this case, you might want to create a class holding the data, which has start and end as properties; then, you can change start and end of entries (ie. expand them) as you please. A List<> could hold the existing entries.

Comment: what if it is the other way around, the one with smallest timespan gets stored, and the larger one gets included later?

Comment: Like I mentioned, that use case is not supported by this code, it just demonstrates how you might go about this. In case of larger period, you'll have to remove the existing one from the dictionary, merge new and existing data and add a new entry.

Comment: I guess your idea could work, Might though be a bit inefficient to perform the check everytime something need to be inserted..

Comment: Using some LINQ statements to find out if there is a fitting instance of the class in the List will cause some overhead. But so will working with a dictionary. This overhead will be very small though, and you could decide to not use LINQ to improve performance. Your use case will have to be rather specific (ie. extremely many inserts) for this to make a real difference.

Comment: this is also during many insert I am encountering this, for one insert I its fine.

Comment: The dictionary approach ensures that I only have unique keys, 
I now need to merge overlapping key entries, and their values.

Comment: Ok, but the dictionaryt approach makes it harder to deal with the case where you wish to expand (or shrink) the time range of entry. Plus, having a class allow you to easily add or adopt functionality in the future. This is often the case: a more flexible approach may be (very slightly!) less efficient or need more coding. This is a trade-off you'll have to decide about.